# Python: How to display log info to file and GUI from two different modules?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to log information to both a log file and GUI Scrolled text window in tkinter. 
I kept my GUI code separate from the logic code, so one file is called gui.py and the other logic.py. gui.py imports logic.py and vice versa.
The log file is written to just fine, regardless if I call logger from my gui or logic code. The GUI window only updates if I call logger from with my GUI code. For some reason, the GUI window will not update if I call logger from within my logic code.  I've seen very few examples of these, except for one with wx.

**gui.py**

`logger = logging.getLogger(_name_)
logger.info("this will print to the GUI scrolled texted`)

**logic.py**

```
import gui

def funtion():
   gui.logger.info("this statement will not print to the GUI, but will print to the console")
```

Can anyone help? I've been searching and trying new techniques for a few days.